# How to insert 2 arrays into mysql database into 2 columns, different rows?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
foreach ($_SESSION['exampleOne'] as $item)
{//insert sql

foreach ($_SESSION['exampleTwo'] as $comment)
{//insert sql
```

How do I merge 2 foreach together?
now my database store like this.. :

```
    comment | item
    ---------------
    Nice!   | Pants
    Great!  | Pants
    Awesome!| Pants
    Nice!   | Skirts
    Great!  | Skirts
    Awesome!| Skirts
    Nice!   | Shirts
    Great!  | Shirts
    Awesome!| Shirts
```

I want it somehow to be like this in my database when I store it:

```
comment | item
---------------
Nice!   | Pants
Great!  | Skirts
Awesome!| Shirts
```

Comment: can  you post 'var_dump($_SESSION["exampleOne"])' for us

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you show the values of your $_SESSION arrays?

Comment: You've basically omitted most of the relevant information: what your arrays contain and what your SQL statements look like.

Comment: `$_SESSION['exampleOne']` is having comments and `$_SESSION['exampleTwo']` is having item ?

Comment: The questions are in your mind only still.. Please express it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this--

```
$merge = array_combine ($_SESSION['exampleOne'],$_SESSION['exampleTwo'])
foreach($merge as $key => $value)
{
    // your insert query
    $query = "insert into tableName set comment='$key', item='$value'";
}
```

Comment: I still don't know what OP is looking for.  This seems correct, except I think the SESSION arrays might need to be boiled down to their unique values with `array_unique`, according to the example in the question.  Still, though, it doesn't make sense to me. :)

Comment: Beware of the SQL injection!